# Does Wordpress.com use ONE set of tables for ALL users?

Tags: mysql, blogs

Does wp.com create a new set of tables for each new blog, or are all blog data stored in one set of tables (with a layout like: http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description)?

Would it ever be a good idea to create a set of tables for each blog in MySQL, or will MySQL be able to handle large numbers of blogs each with their comments/tags/categories/posts stored in one set of tables?

Comment: Yes.  I'll offer this as a comment because it's hearsay: I was at the MySQL Conference last April and I sat down to eat lunch at a random table.  The database architect from wordpress.com was sitting at the table, and we talked about his site.  He said they manage thousands of separate databases, which makes it simpler to do backups, migrate blogs to different servers, etc.

Comment: That said, it's probably **premature optimization** to split up the data like that, unless you're operating at the scale of a wordpress.com.  In fact, that same DB architect said they had started out using a single database, but as they grew they realized they had to split up the data.

Comment: OK, thanks Bill. So they said it isn't necessarily a good idea to start out with what one would need for massive traffic? I just don't want to shoot myself in the foot by not ensuring the DB can be scaled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For how Wordpress does it, have a look at [Wordpress MU](http://mu.wordpress.org/)

I imagine at a quick *guess* there's a shared user table and each blog gets it's own DB as the relations between objects only apply within a individual blog.

Edit: From the MU FAQ:

> WordPress MU creates tables for each
>   blog, which is the system we found
>   worked best for plugin compatibility
>   and scaling after lots of testing and
>   trial and error. This takes advantage
>   of existing OS-level and MySQL query
>   caches and also makes it infinitely
>   easier to segment user data, which is
>   what all services that grow beyond a
>   single box eventually have to do.